# How to make MS Access pass-through query run correctly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

When I run this pass-through query from Microsoft Access that uses an odbc connection it works fine:

```
SELECT   b.PRODUCT, b.UPC_NBR, b.EAN_NBR, b.NAME AS ProductDescription, b.AUTHOR, 
     o.RETAILER, o.REFER_NBR, o.ARDESC, a.NAME, o.TRAN_DATE, 
     o.QTY, o.RETAIL, o.PRICE, o.COST

FROM    BOOK_MASTER_REC as b JOIN 
    ORBDETL_RECORD as o ON ISBN_TITLE = o.TITLE 
                 AND ISBN_PUBLISHER = o.BK_PUBL 
                 AND BOOK_GROUP = o.BK_GROUP  
                 AND BOOK_PREFIX = o.BK_PREFIX JOIN 
    ARDESC_RECORD as a ON o.ARDESC = a.ARDESC 

WHERE b.PRODUCT Between 600 And 698
```

When I run an identical query from SMSS that uses the same odbc connection via linked server it fails:

```
SELECT b.PRODUCT, b.UPC_NBR, b.EAN_NBR, b.NAME AS ProductDescription, b.AUTHOR, 
     o.RETAILER, o.REFER_NBR, o.ARDESC, a.NAME, o.TRAN_DATE, 
     o.QTY, o.RETAIL, o.PRICE, o.COST

FROM    DPS_GPR..root.BOOK_MASTER_REC as b INNER JOIN 
    DPS_GPR..root.ORBDETL_RECORD as o ON ISBN_TITLE = o.TITLE 
                         AND ISBN_PUBLISHER = o.BK_PUBL 
                         AND BOOK_GROUP = o.BK_GROUP  
                         AND BOOK_PREFIX = o.BK_PREFIX INNER JOIN 
    DPS_GPR..root.ARDESC_RECORD as a ON o.ARDESC = a.ARDESC 

WHERE b.PRODUCT Between 600 And 698
```

It gives the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DPS_GPR" returned message
>   "[Transoft][TSODBC][usqlsd]')' expected here (FROM)". Msg 7321, Level
>   16, State 2, Line 2 An error occurred while preparing the query
>   "SELECT
>   Col1061,Col1062,Col1064,Col1065,Col1066,Col1042,Col1048,Col1049,Col1050,Col1051,Col1052,Col1053,Col1054,Tbl1005.NAME
>   Col1040 FROM root.ARDESC_RECORD Tbl1005,(SELECT
>   Col1057,Col1058,Col1059,Col1060,Col1061,Col1062,Col1064,Col1065,Col1066,Tbl1003.RETAILER
>   Col1042,Tbl1003.BK_PREFIX Col1043,Tbl1003.BK_GROUP
>   Col1044,Tbl1003.BK_PUBL Col1045,Tbl1003.TITLE
>   Col1046,Tbl1003.REFER_NBR Col1048,Tbl1003.ARDESC
>   Col1049,Tbl1003.TRAN_DATE Col1050,Tbl1003.QTY Col1051,Tbl1003.RETAIL
>   Col1052,Tbl1003.PRICE Col1053,Tbl1003.COST
>   Col1054,Col1067,Col1063,Tbl1003.SEQ Col1047,Tbl1003.PROCESSED_FLAG
>   Col1055 FROM root.ORBDETL_RECORD Tbl1003,(SELECT Tbl1001.BOOK_PREFIX
>   Col1057,Tbl1001.BOOK_GROUP Col1058,Tbl1001.ISBN_PUBLISHER
>   Col1059,Tbl1001.ISBN_TITLE Col1060,Tbl1001.UPC_NBR
>   Col1061,Tbl1001.EAN_NBR Col1062,Tbl1001.NAME Col1064,Tbl1001.AUTHOR
>   Col1065,Tbl1001.PRODUCT Col1066,Tbl1001.CATEGORY9
>   Col1067,Tbl1001.BOOK_NUMBER Col1063 FROM root.BOOK_MASTER_REC Tbl1001
>   WHERE Tbl1001.PRODUCT>=(600.) AND Tbl1001.PRODUCT<=(698.)) Qry1068
>   WHERE Col1060=Tbl1003.TITLE AND Col1059=Tbl1003.BK_PUBL AND
>   Col1058=Tbl1003.BK_GROUP AND Col1057=Tbl1003.BK_PREFIX) Qry1069 WHERE
>   Col1049=Tbl1005.ARDESC" for execution against OLE DB provider
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "DPS_GPR".

I would appreciate any ideas as to how I might get this working through SQL Server as I'm trying to get away from MS Access.

Comment: Your four-part table name reference ("DPS_GPR..root.BOOK_MASTER_REC") looks odd.  Could you explain why you have nothing in position two, and "root" in position three?  That's not necessarily wrong, but it is fairly unusual.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Man, I wish I knew cause I've been wondering the same thing.  All I know is that this is using ODBC drivers to a proprietary db, and I know it works fine when I "SELECT * FROM DPS_GPR..root.TableName".  But apparently it's not handling these joins too well from SSMS.

Comment: FYI, only reason I thought to try it this way was because in MS Access I saw the link was to "root.BOOK_MASTER_REC".  So I gave it a shot and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by making it a pass-through query.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DPS_GPR, 'select ... blah blah blah ...')
```

Not as ideal of a solution as I was hoping for, but it works.